# Reading SQL deadlock graph

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-profiler, database-deadlocks

Can someone please help me to read/understand this deadlock graph?

I don't understand why process 75 is requesting a lock on an object that he has a lock on already?

[image: Deadlock graph]

Comment: can you send "show innoDB status" response it will be more informative. It should contain last deadlock

Comment: @varela - This is SQL Server. jaques What version? Looks like a paralellism issue.

Comment: @Martin Smith. SQL Server 2008

Comment: @jaques - If you post your relevant table structures, including indexes, and the XML version of the deadlock graph into your question you may well be able to get a more specific answer.

Comment: @Martin. This is a commercial product and I don't feel comfortable exposing the internals

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to a blog article that I've found the existance of an "Exchange Event" indicates that the source of your problem **may** be parallelism in your query.

[Today's Annoyingly-Unwieldy Term: "Intra-Query Parallel Thread Deadlocks"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2008/09/24/today-s-annoyingly-unwieldy-term-intra-query-parallel-thread-deadlocks.aspx)

The above article goes into much more detail, however the punchline is:

> **Workaround #1:** Add an index or improve the query to eliminate the need for parallelism.  In most cases, the use of parallelism in a query indicates that you have a very large scan, sort, or join that isn't supported by proper indexes.  If you tune the query, you will often find that you end up with a much quicker and more efficient plan that doesn't use parallelism, and therefore isn't subject to this type of problem. Of course, in some queries (DSS/OLAP-type queries, in particular) it may be difficult to eliminate all large scans.
>
> **Workaround #2:**  Force single-threaded execution with an "OPTION (MAXDOP 1)" query hint at the end of the query.  If you can't modify the query, you can apply the hint to any query with a plan guide.

You might want to try this to see if there is any improvement.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to identify and improve a slow running query and no locks since then. Not sure how to prevent this in the future? And why does SQL server try to be smart if there is a possibility that it might itself into a deadlock situation? (E.G Why use parallelism?)

Comment: The referenced link is focused on "pure" exchange event intra-query deadlock where there is just one SPID (thus "intra-query").  The questions's deadlock graph includes an exchange event _plus_ a more traditional deadlock involving 2 queries (another SPID).  I have read that isolated deadlocking exchange events can fix themselves (as they may be due to internal bugs) so the focus should be on the other shared objects--page locks in this case.